# Parallel fitting on Mathematica

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting, data-analysis, least-squares

I have a data that looks like as follows

```
data=
Table[
    Table[
            a[[i]]*j+1,
        ,{j,dataLength}]
    ,{i,numOfDatasets}]
```

I would like to fit these datasets with a NonlinearModelFit[]

```
Table[
    NonlinearModelFit[data[[i]], a x + b, {a,b},x]
,{i,NumberOfDatasets}]
```

The function I would like to fit isn't linear, but this is just an example.

My problem is that I need to parallelize such an operation. I have tried doing it with ParallelTable, but I get dozens of errors. Do you, guys, know how this is done?

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: Try posting your question on our [sister Mathematica site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions):

Answer (score 1):

After renaming your initial array `a` to `arr` and just writing `ParallelTable` works for me:

```
dataLength = 10
numOfDatasets = 5
arr = Table[RandomInteger[i], {i, 1, numOfDatasets}]
data = Table[Table[arr[[i]], {j, dataLength}], {i, numOfDatasets}]
ParallelTable[NonlinearModelFit[data[[i]], a x + b, {a, b}, x], {i, numOfDatasets}]
```

Output:

> {FittedModel[1. -1.13164*10^-17 x],FittedModel[2. -2.26329*10^-17
>   x],FittedModel[1. -1.13164*10^-17 x],FittedModel[3.],FittedModel[1.
>   -1.13164*10^-17 x]}

Most likely, Mathematica got confused by your data array `a` and the fit parameter `a` in your Table statement.